# need help hooking up an oled display

Tags: i2c, display

recently i bought this oled display .

[image]

http://www.wvshare.com/product/0.96inch-OLED-A.htm

how can i connect it with arduino . Driver Chip is SSD1306 . Supported Interface are 3-wire SPI, 4-wire SPI, I2C . it's can display two colors Yellow and Blue.

i need some guidance on how to hook it up with arduino lets say using i2c protocol . and is there any existing library ?

Note : on the wvshare website there's only code sample for STM32 Microcontrollers .

Comment: Did you read the datasheet? https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/SSD1306.pdf

Comment: Are you prepared to resolder the resistors on the back?

Comment: @jippie i read the datasheet. it seems i can use the DIN and CLK pin as SDA and SCL. i tried that but its not working .  Ignacio, which resistor ? i know some basic soldering. thanks

Comment: You have to remove the 0-ohm resistor `BS1` from the `0` position and move it the the `1` position.

Comment: has anyone tried it with i2c? been 2 days now trying to make it work .resolder the resistors but dosn't want to work.
and after the soldering wich library should i choose ?

Answer (score 2):

it's working with u8glib.  but i am using  4-wire SPI.

constructor for U8GLIB

```
U8GLIB_SSD1306_128X64 u8g(13, 11, 10, 9,8);
```

Pin configuration was

```
Arduino -   Oled Display
13 -    CLK
11 -    DIN (SI)
10 -    CS
9 - D/C (A0)
8 - RES
```

the reset pin is required. i used 3.3v  arduino pin for vcc .

Comment: Yes, that is what the silkscreened chart shows the installed resistors as selecting for operating mode.  Gerben had been suggesting you could do i2c if you changed them.